# Getting index.html content while trying to scrape a react website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping

when i try to scrape a reactjs website using nodejs i am getting the content of index.html file only not the tags that were used in the website.
Here is what i have tried -

```
    const request = require("request");
    const cheerio = require("cheerio");

    const URL = "https://pydata-jal.netlify.com/";

    request(URL, (err, res, body) => {
      if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log($.html());
      }
    });
```

What should i do to get the whole of tags that were used in react website.

And do tell i can scrape the hackernoon website ? (for just example)
if its legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheerio parses only already rendered HTML (eg: static HTML)
In order to get the React render you should rely on headless browsers controlled with tools like [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/)

Comment: means we can never scrap a react website using cheerio??

Comment: Yes, cheerios parses the html content and let you access to nodes in jQuery fashion. React needs a browser core in order to render correctly (javascript has to be executed and DOM manipulated and reconciled with Virtual DOM)